# PipeSecurity use with named pipes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, named-pipes

I try to use a `NamedPipeServerStream`. For this I need to give the authorisation so I do :

```
PipeSecurity ps = new PipeSecurity();
ps.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(@"Everyone", 
                                    PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite | 
                                    PipeAccessRights.CreateNewInstance, 
                                    AccessControlType.Allow));

server = new NamedPipeServerStream(name, PipeDirection.Out, 

                                    NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances, 
                                   PipeTransmissionMode.Message, 
                                   PipeOptions.None, 
                                   1, 
                                   1, 
                                   ps);
```

But I have an error saying that this:

> [ constructor for `NamedPipeServerStream` doesn't exist ]

...and I don't find any other way to give the permission without that.

Thanks

Comment: What framework are you targeting ? The constructor signature you are using is not supported by .net standard  and .net core

Comment: I need to use the DLL made by the .Net Standard in a UWP so I think only .Net Standard 2.0 can work